# Styling submit button with CSS for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, selector

For Firefox, and Chrome `input[type=button]:hover,input[type=submit]:hover` and `input[type=button],input[type=submit]` will do the job, but what to do with IE (8)?

@Herohtar:
They do? How's that? I'm using this css and they won't work:

```
    input[type=button],input[type=submit]
{
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: black;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',times,serif;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    background: #fceabb; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%, #fccd4d 50%, #f8b500 51%, #fbdf93 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fceabb), color-stop(50%,#fccd4d), color-stop(51%,#f8b500), color-stop(100%,#fbdf93)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fceabb', endColorstr='#fbdf93',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}

input[type=button]:hover,input[type=submit]:hover
{
    color: black;   
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -khtml-border-radius:6px;
    background: #ffb76b; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb76b 0%, #ffa73d 50%, #ff7c00 51%, #ff7f04 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb76b), color-stop(50%,#ffa73d), color-stop(51%,#ff7c00), color-stop(100%,#ff7f04)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb76b', endColorstr='#ff7f04',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`input[type=submit]` and `input[type=button]` both work in IE8, as well as with the :hover condition.

**Edit:** The CSS you listed there works perfectly for me in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/dnZNE/ Maybe something else in your CSS is overriding it?

Comment: well, after I have input[type="button"]:disabled,input[type="submit"]:disabled,input[type="text"]:disabled,select[disabled]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; do you have just that single line, or is there more to it? Also, would it be possible to see the actual page?

Comment: I like the site you linked here, but NOW I'M TOTALLY CONFUSED! When i paste my html and css there, page is shown just the way it should be!

Comment: Actual page is www.rssmagnet.net/en/login.php (when you take a look at how does it looks like in IE, you'll understand why i want to redesign it :P)

Comment: That's really strange... the CSS on that page indeed does not work in IE8. At first glance everything seems to be okay. I tried a few things with it, but couldn't make it work... I don't understand what's causing it to break like that.

Comment: Okay, even with just a plain HTML file that has nothing but a button and the CSS, it doesn't work, so apparently there *is* a problem with IE... I don't know why it works in jsfiddle though, if that is the case.

Comment: I just don't have any luck :\

Comment: By the way, the styling partially works if you add a class to the button and then use the class selector instead of input[type=submit]; however, IE8 also seems to have an issue with :hover, so it only works halfway... This page http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html has a fix, but even that seems to still have a few issues. You might give that a try though.

Comment: Just had this problem because I used `filter` to set a gradient background on hover, and had to explicitly set `filter: none` in another `:hover` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible use jQuery (www.jquery.com):

`$(':submit').css( 'attribute', 'value' );`

If it's not I'm afraid you have to add class to those buttons.

Comment: Adding a class? I feel that implementing "hover" could be complicated, right? Please tell me that my feeling is wrong and i wouldn't have to use javascript for implementing "hover"! :)

Comment: Well, the problem is probably with the [type=submit] part, not the "hover". I don't really have IE8 to test it, but I remember it being a problem in IE7. One solution was to use jQuery to fix IE quirks, the other one was to write a classname. But then again - IE8 might just work fine with both selectors.

Comment: This may turn out to be the only solution, unless you can figure out why the CSS works through jsfiddle and implement that... it's actually not too difficult to implement hover effects using jQuery.

Comment: i have never used jQuery, have no idea about it (although, i'm ok with Javascript).

Comment: Try it. It's unobtrusive (when used properly), clean and very fast. There are a lot of good examples on their website (jquery.com).